# What are some of the main high level approaches to applying ML on kinematic sensor data?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, signal-processing

I've just started a project which will involve having to detect certain events in a stream of kinematic sensor data. By searching through the literature, I've found a lot of highly specific papers, but no general reviews.

If I search up on computer vision, I'm likely to get 100s of articles giving overviews of different types of architectures for various vision tasks. They would look something like this:

- We mainly use CNNs which work like this ...
- For object detection we use one or two stage detectors which look like this...
- For video classification we can use 3D CNNs or RNNs...
- .... etc

So I'm looking for something similar with regard to kinematic motion sensors. As was [pointed out to me](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/72811/what-are-some-of-the-main-high-level-approaches-for-analysis-of-kinematic-sensor) on the signal processing SE, "kinematic" could mean a lot of things. So specifically, I'm referring to 1d time series data for:

- acceleration/velocity/position
- angular velocity / absolute orientation

Comment: 1D CNNs could help for time series. LSTM can be used to predict next value in a time series and anomaly detection. More info on patterns recognition in time series here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752727/pattern-recognition-in-time-series